# Cancel AsyncOperation after some time WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await

I'm trying to execute Python Script using Skulpt in `WebView`. If python script contains an infinite loop Application gives no response.

Executing Python Script from C#

```
await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("evalPy", new string[1] { script });
```

In JavaScript:

```
function evalPy(script) {
    try {
        var result = Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, script);
        return Sk.builtins.repr(result).v;
    } catch (err) {

    }
}
```

`InvokeScriptAsync` is `async` operation there might be some way to cancel it at any point.

My first attempt to stop java script after some time:

```
var task = webView.InvokeScriptAsync("evalPy", new string[1] { script }).AsTask<string>();
task.Wait(2000);
task.AsAsyncOperation<string>().Cancel();
```

Second Attempt:

```
var op = webView.InvokeScriptAsync("evalPy", new string[1] { script });
new Task(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    op.Cancel();
    op.Close();
}).Start();
```

Also tried to setTimeout in JavaScript

```
function evalPy(script) {
    try {
        var result = Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, script);
        setTimeout(function () { throw "Times-out"; }, 2000);

        return Sk.builtins.repr(result).v;
    } catch (err) {
    }
}
```

[CodeSkulptor.org](http://codeskulptor.org) is also using Skulpt to execute Python Script in Web Browser and stops execution of Python Script after some time.

Comment: When you `await`, the method wont return to the JavaScript until the execution is complete. Hence an infinite loop will never return. What happens when you wait for two seconds then cancel?

Comment: When I wait for two seconds then cancel, infinite loop continues. Debugger shows task status as cancelled but app don't response

Comment: The python process will continue execution but your method call should return. Are you doing anything else inside the method call?

Comment: Yes python Script execution continues but method call returns. No I'm not doing anything else in method call.

Comment: How about creating two tasks, one which is simply `Task.Delay` and the other which is the script in question. Then use `Task.WaitAny`. At the end, if the task is still running, cancel it and continue.

Answer (score 1):

I've just crawled out of the Codecademy,s html course and don't really know the details, but javascript is a single threaded language and I heard you need a web worker to multi-thread.

```
importScripts('./skulpt.js');
importScripts('./skulpt.min.js');
importScripts('./skulpt-stdlib.js');

// file level scope code gets executed when loaded


// Executed when the function postMessage on
//the worker object is called.
// onmessage must be global
onmessage = function(e){
  var out = [];
  try{
    Sk.configure({output:function (t){out.push(t);}});
    Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>",false,e.data);
  }catch(e){out.push(e.toString());}
  postMessage(out.join(''));
}
```

main page script(not tested):

```
var skulptWorker = new Worker('SkulptWorker.js');
skulptWorker.onmessage = function(e){
  //Writing skulpt output to console
  console.log(e.data);
  running = false;
}
var running = true;
skulptWorker.postMessage('print(\'hello world\')');
running = true;
skulptWorker.postMessage('while True:\n    print(\'hello world\')');


setTimeout(function(){
    if(running) skulptWorker.terminate();},5000);
```

There is a drawback though, when I use input() in the python code, skulpt throws an error that it cannot find the window object as it's in a worker thread and I have no solution to that yet.

p.s.
Some testing revealed the code below freezes the main thread(spamming postMessage is a bad idea):

SkulptWorker.js:

```
importScripts('./skulpt.js');
importScripts('./skulpt.min.js');
importScripts('./skulpt-stdlib.js');

// file level scope code gets executed when loaded


// Executed when the function postMessage on
//the worker object is called.
// onmessage must be global
onmessage = function(e){
  try{
    Sk.configure({output:function (t){postMessage(t);}});
    Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>",false,e.data);
  }catch(e){postMessage(e.toString());}
}
```